# NA.locf carrying over data headers, R, Zoo Package

Tags: r, zoo

I am attempting to use the `na.locf` function in the `zoo` package to fill some `NA` variables in a time series. Unfortunately when I use the function it fills in rows that are completely blank with the data header. Code and example below:

```
comp_homicide3 = na.locf(comp_homicide3, na.rm = TRUE, is.character = F, fromLast = F)
```

Example:

```
Djibouti NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
Sweden .4, .7, NA, .3, NA

na.locf
Djibouti Djibouti, Djibouti, Djibouti, Djibouti, Djibouti
Sweden .4, .7, .7, .3, .3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your questions in a reproducible form when posing questions on SO.  We can't really tell exactly what you have but if we write the following reproducible code it seems to give the expected answer:

```
library(zoo)

Lines <- "Djibouti NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
Sweden .4, .7, NA, .3, NA"  
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
> na.locf(DF, na.rm = TRUE)
        V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1 Djibouti <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   Sweden  0.4  0.7 <NA>  0.3 <NA>
```